# Excel VBA to get Random Integer Values without repetitions

Tags: excel, vba, random

Write a subroutine in VBA to generate a winning lotto ticket consisting of 6 integer numbers randomly drawn from 1 to 40.

In order to have a small simulation animation, range("A1:E8") should contain the numbers 1 to 40 and the subroutine should then cycle through these numbers using a colored cell and then momentarily pause 2 seconds on a selected winning number. The list of winning numbers drawn should then be printed in the range("G2:G7"). In case a number drawn has already been drawn previously in the list, then a new number should be redrawn.

I have only been able to do as follows.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test1()
  Sheet1.Cells.Clear
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To 40
      Cells(i, 1) = i
  Next
End Sub

'-----------------------------
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Function arraydemo(r As Range)
  Dim cell As Range, i As Integer, x(40, 1) As Double
  i = 1
  For Each cell In r
      x(i, 1) = cell.Value
      i = i + 1
  Next cell
  arraydemo = x
End Function
Sub test3()
  Dim x() As String
  chose = Int(Rnd * UBound(x))
End Sub
```

I got stuck elsewhere, the sub test3(), does not seem appropriate here. I need some suggestions. Also, I appologise for my poor formatting, I am new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Populating your range like this:

> range("A1:E8") should contain the numbers 1 to 40

```
Sheet1.Cells.Clear

Dim i As Integer
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Range("A1:E8")
For i = 1 To 40
    rng
Next
```

> generate a winning lotto ticket consisting of 6 integer numbers randomly drawn from 1 to 40

Using a dictionary object to keep track of which items have been picked (and prevent duplicate) in a `While` loop (until there are 6 numbers chosen):

```
Dim picked as Object
Set picked = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Select six random numbers:
i = 1
While picked.Count < 6
    num = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 40)
    If Not picked.Exists(num) Then
        picked.Add num, i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Wend
```

Using the `Application.Wait` method to do the "pause", you can set up a procedure like so:

```
'Now, show those numbers on the sheet, highlighting each cell for 2 seconds
For Each val In picked.Keys()
    rng.Cells(picked(val)).Interior.ColorIndex = 39 'Modify as needed
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    rng.Cells(picked(val)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Next
```

> The list of winning numbers drawn should then be printed in the range("G2:G7").

Print the keys from the `picked` dictionary:

```
Range("G2:G7").Value = Application.Transpose(picked.Keys())
```

**Putting it all together:**

```
Sub Lotto()
    Dim i As Integer, num As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim picked As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim val As Variant


    'Populate the sheet with values 1:40 in range A1:E8
    Set rng = Range("A1:E8")
    For i = 1 To 40
        rng.Cells(i) = i
    Next

    'Store which numbers have been already chosen
    Set picked = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Select six random numbers:
    i = 1
    While picked.Count < 6
        num = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 40)
        If Not picked.Exists(num) Then
            picked.Add num, i
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend

    'Now, show those numbers on the sheet, highlighting each cell for 2 seconds
    For Each val In picked.Keys()
        rng.Cells(val).Interior.ColorIndex = 39 'Modify as needed
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        rng.Cells(val).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Next

    'Display the winning series of numbers in G2:G7
    Range("G2:G7").Value = Application.Transpose(picked.Keys())
End Sub
```

**NOTE** This absolutely will not work on Excel for Mac, you would need to use a Collection instead of a Dictionary, as the Scripting.Runtime library is not available on Mac OS.

Comment: Some how this feels like you just did the OP's homework for him.  I wish I knew you back in high school. :)  But I will add this page to my favorites as I can see using variations of this for other things.

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah, I probably did. There was some effort given in the OP, though, and it was a relatively simple and interesting problem to play with :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the excellent answer given by member David Zemens, following is the universal function written in "pure" Excel VBA, which does not contain any Excel Worksheet Functions, neither Dictionary Object (re: `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"`).

```
Option Explicit

'get N random integer numbers in the range from LB to UB, NO repetition
'general formula: Int ((UpperBound - LowerBound + 1) * Rnd + LowerBound)
Function RandomNumbers(LB As Integer, UB As Integer, N As Integer) As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim arrRandom() As Integer
    Dim colRandom As New Collection
    Dim colItem As Variant
    Dim tempInt As Integer
    Dim tempExists As Boolean

    'check that ArraySize is less that the range of the integers
    If (UB - LB + 1 >= N) Then

        While colRandom.Count < N

            Randomize
            ' get random number in interval
            tempInt = Int((UB - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB)

            'check if number exists in collection
            tempExists = False
            For Each colItem In colRandom
                If (tempInt = colItem) Then
                    tempExists = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next colItem

            ' add to collection if not exists
            If Not tempExists Then
                colRandom.Add tempInt
            End If
        Wend

        'convert collection to array
        ReDim arrRandom(N - 1)
        For I = 0 To N - 1
            arrRandom(I) = colRandom(I + 1)
        Next I

        'return array of random numbers
        RandomNumbers = arrRandom
    Else
        RandomNumbers = Nothing
    End If
End Function

'get 5 Random numbers in the ranger 1...10 and populate Worksheet
Sub GetRandomArray()
    Dim arr() As Integer

    'get array of 5 Random numbers in the ranger 1...10
    arr = RandomNumbers(1, 10, 5)

    'populate Worksheet Range with 5 random numbers from array
    If (IsArray(arr)) Then
        Range("A1:A5").Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End If
End Sub
```

The function

```
Function RandomNumbers(LB As Integer, UB As Integer, N As Integer)
```

returns array of N random numbers in the range LB...UB inclusively without repetition.

Sample `Sub GetRandomArray()` demonstrates how to get 5 random numbers in the range 1...10 and populate the Worksheet Range: it could be customized for any particular requirements (e.g. 8 from 1...40 in PO requirements).

---

APPENDIX A (Courtesy of David Ziemens)

**Alternatively**, you can do similar without relying on Collection object at all. Build a delimited string, and then use the `Split` function to cast the string to an array, and return that to the calling procedure.

This actually returns the numbers as `String`, but that shouldn't matter for this particular use-case, and if it does, can easily be modified.

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
Dim arr As Variant

arr = RandomNumbersNoCollection(1, 40, 6)

End Sub


'get N random integer numbers in the range from LB to UB, NO repetition
'general formula: Int ((UpperBound - LowerBound + 1) * Rnd + LowerBound)
Function RandomNumbersNoCollection(LB As Integer, UB As Integer, N As Integer)
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim numbers As String ' delimited string
    Dim tempInt As Integer
    Const dlmt As String = "|"

    'check that ArraySize is less that the range of the integers
    If (UB - LB + 1 >= N) Then

            ' get random number in interval
        Do
            Randomize
            tempInt = Int((UB - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB)
            If Len(numbers) = 0 Then
                numbers = tempInt & dlmt
            ElseIf InStr(1, numbers, tempInt & dlmt) = 0 Then
                numbers = numbers & tempInt & dlmt
            End If

        Loop Until UBound(Split(numbers, dlmt)) = 6
        numbers = Left(numbers, Len(numbers) - 1)
    End If
    RandomNumbersNoCollection = Split(numbers, dlmt)

End Function
```

Comment: Cool. If you don't mind using `Variant()` instead of `Integer()` you can actually simplify this quite a bit.  I'll add another option to your answer.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks David. Actually I was considering that option (i.e. to create string and use Instr() function), but then decided to stay with collection as a valid option, thus avoiding Split() and other string operations, including underlying string-to-integer type casting. Anyway, thanks for your time and kind attention. Best regards,